# boto3 pagination with route53domains

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-route53

Trying to see about using pagination to list our registered domains using a Python script with boto3. We currently have 200 and the MaxItems is 100. Trying to figure out a way to paginate in pages of 20. I checked boto3 documentation for Route 53 which is what I am using for this and Googled around with no success.

Tried various methods of pagination, but getting errors each time. Wondering if pagination is supported for Route 53.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 

import boto3
import json

listofdomains = []

client = boto3.client('route53domains', region_name='us-east-1')
r = client.list_domains(
    #Marker='NextPageMarker',
    MaxItems=100
)


for i in r['Domains']:
   listofdomains.append(i['DomainName'])
   print(i['DomainName'])

finallist = json.dumps(listofdomains)
print finallist
```

Comment: You should try getting a paginator like `p = client.get_paginator('list_domains')` and then loop over each page like `for page in p.paginate():`

Answer (score 2):

The way your code is asking for the list of domains, you are asking for a single "page" of listed results to be returned, and as you mentioned, there is a maximum size for the list of 100. Instead, get a paginator for the `list_domains` method using `client.get_paginator('list_domains')`, and use that paginator to iterate through each page of results, one at a time:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import boto3
import json

listofdomains = []

client = boto3.client('route53domains', region_name='us-east-1')

# Use a pager instead
p = client.get_paginator('list_domains')
for page in p.paginate():
    for i in page['Domains']:
        dom = i['DomainName']
        listofdomains.append(dom)
        print(dom)    

finallist = json.dumps(listofdomains)
print(finallist)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a note that `us-east-1` is the only region allowed to list domains. And I am not sure if Using the Config object is more appropriate because I found how to reset default regions from [Boto3 docs][1]. Then everything else is like what @charlesreid1 has done.

```
from botocore.config import Config

my_config = Config(
    region_name = 'us-east-1',
    signature_version = 'v4',
    retries = {
        'max_attempts': 10,
        'mode': 'standard'
    }
)

client = boto3.client('route53domains', config=my_config)


  [1]: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html?highlight=region
```